# Crate DB Trigger implementation

Tags: triggers, crate, cratedb

Our application has a requirement to be notified so that we launch a Python application, everytime a record gets inserted into a particular table, in traditional Databases it can be done using DB Triggers, is there a way to achieve similar functionality in Crate DB. I did read about using the Crate Plugin classes, but I do not see a way to get notified whenever a record gets inserted into a Table. If anyone has been able to achieve this functionality in Crate DB please let me know.
Cheers!

Comment: There is currently (as of CrateDB 2.3) no support for triggers, but you could upvote the issue requesting support for it: https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/1376

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only obvious way is by polling the table.
You could achieve that by writing a plugin but this seems rather overengineered